# Encoding # in FTP user/password within URL

Tags: ftp, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to access a password-protected ftp site. I have user "foo" pass "pass#1"
When I enter them directly, it works.

I am now trying to craft a single URL that contains the user/pass within (e.g. `ftp://foo:pass%231@ftp.arsecommerce.com/`), but it doens't work. I tried URLEncoding the # and failed.

How do I properly encode the # sign?

Comment: This method works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Indeed, I tested with Firefox and Wireshark, and `pass%231` is being transmitted as `pass#1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `%23` to replace the hash `#` sign in `pass#1`.

```
ftp://foo:pass%231@domain.tld:port
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding - Has to use Percent-Encoding.